# Receiving POST data in PHP from ASP app

Tags: php, asp.net, post

I have a PHP page set up to receive `POST` data from a Windows based ASP.NET app.
The PHP script does a `var_dump($_POST)` into a database table of which I can view in phpmyadmin for debugging (although I haven't got this far yet...). The PHP script then echos `completed` as a response which the ASP app receives as an "everything's OK" message and sends the next `POST`.

The problem is that PHP never receives the `POST` data, am I tackling this correctly or do I need to receive the `POST` data in a different way other than reading the `$_POST` variable?

UPDATE:

```
include('database.class.php'); //this has a constructor that defines $link.

if(isset($_POST)) {
    if(empty($_POST)) {
        echo 'no data';
    } else {
        $data = var_dump($_POST);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `net_dump` (`dump`) VALUES ('$data')";
        mysqli_query($db -> link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db -> link));
        echo 'completed';
    }
} else {
    echo 'no data';
}
```

FINAL UPDATE:

The ASP app was sending `POST` data in `JSON` content type, fixed using `file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: We love the theory. However till we see your code, none of us will be able to kick in

Comment: Sure do wish you'd post some code.

Comment: Do you know that you're actually reaching the php page? Have you tried showing errors or just exiting the page when you get there?

Comment: The app definitely gets there... if I echo 'Hello PHP' on the page the app prints 'Hello PHP'. The app was developed by a third party, I will update the question with PHP now.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` reveal? @Edward Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. As well as `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()` or equivalent to catch DB error.

Comment: Apologies; error reporting is already on in `.ini` file, will put in die command now, btw the `POST` encoding is `JSON`, will try `php://input` too.

Comment: Fixed: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php
PHP expects POST data in native format, not JSON.

Comment: make sure the request has `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, if you want to use $_POST, also you have a serious sql injection $query string

Comment: @RonniSkansing you are right it is an encoding issue. I know there is a horrendous injection risk, but this is for debugging purposes only, thank you for your concern though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP expects `POST` data to be in *native* format ie: `key1=value1&key2=value2` to receive data in a different encoding ie `JSON` you must receive the raw `POST` data using: `file_get_contents("php://input");`